# MSDASQL provider throws error for cloudera Impala : Requested conversion is not supported

Tags: sql-server, odbc, cloudera, impala, linked-server

We are trying to pull unicode data from Cloudera Impala into SQL Server. We have done the below steps:

1. We have installed Cloudera Impala ODBC driver and configured DSN. We have enabled "SQL Unicode Types" in the DSN settings.

[image: Use SQL Unicode Types]

2. We have created linked server in SQL Server accordingly for the DSN. We have set the option "Collation Compatibility" to True.

When we run the below query, we are getting error as given below:

```sql
SELECT *
from openquery
(LinkedServerName,'SELECT  columnName from SchemaName.ViewName where col_id = ''ABCDEFGH''')
```

> OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LinkedServerName"
> returned message "Requested conversion is not supported.". Msg 7341,
> Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot get the current row value of column
> "[MSDASQL].columnName" from OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked
> server "LinkedServerName".

We also tried below CASTING:

1. Using CAST to VARCHAR(50)

```sql
SELECT CAST(columnName AS VARCHAR(50))
```

But, we get the below error:

> Msg 7355, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for
> linked server "linkedServer" supplied inconsistent metadata for a
> column. The name was changed at execution time.

**Note:**
When we disable "Enable SQL unicode datatypes" in DSN settings, we are able to pull data without issues. But, the unicode characters are coming as boxes.

can you please help us, in resolving the issue.

Comment: What version of the Impala ODBC driver do you have installed on the SQL Server?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning, latest Cloudera Impala ODBC driver : 2.06.00.1000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We were able to fix the unicode issue, by going with below settings for cloudera Impala ODBC 64 bit driver and linked server.

1. **64 bit ODBC driver settings in DSN for cloudera Impala**

[image: ODBC driver settings]

[image: ODBC driver advanced settings]

2. **Linked Server settings in SQL Server**

[image: Linked Server Settings]